# Why is this swap function call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I wanted to swap two number using a template but why does this  swap(x, y); give an error as an ambiguous call.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

void swap(T &a, T &b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main () {
    int x = 14;
    int y = 7;
    swap(x, y);
    cout << x << y;
}
```

Comment: there may already be a swap function

Comment: @LoganMurphy: That is not what "class" means in template land... not even close. Any type will do.

Comment: Because you did `using namespace std;` and `<iostream>` has been known to include `<algorithm>` (or `<utility>` in C++11), but to my knowledge, not much anymore with newer versions of implementations.

Comment: By any chance is this not your actual code and, if so, does your actual code include `<algorithm>` and a `using namespace std;` or another file which defines `swap` (or includes `<algorithm>`)?

Comment: At least it didn't give you an androgynous call error.

Comment: Your edit shows `using namespace std;` now.  That would be your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys i changed the swap to swaap and it worked fine!

Comment: @Chiran, Better yet, don't do `using namespace std;` and put it in your own namespace, even if it's an anonymous one.

Comment: Lots of good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077

Comment: ...changing your function name to `swaap` is probably the worst way to fix this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

`iostream` must be including `algorithm` and, since you decided to include the entire `std` namespace in your file, you have a collision with `std::swap`.  Remove `using namespace std;`

EDIT: As @chris points out in the comments, `std::swap` was moved to `<utility>` in C++11.

Comment: And if it's C++11, one of those must be including `<utility>`.

Comment: @chris: Ah yeah, good point